# Hyphenation in "First computer crime targeted laws"

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, hyphenation, format

I am preparing a presentation for my English class. My question is whether the phrase

> First computer crime targeted laws

should have any hyphens in it such as

> computer-crime-targeted

Comment: The fact you have a problem indicates there is something wrong with the phrase. What? Because you have a string of nouns used as adjectives its not clear which goes with which, and hyphens don't seem to work. Solution — rephrase using a preposition: "First laws targeted at computer crime". Just one two-letter preposition and it's now immediately comprehensible. Your English teacher will be amazed, and where you can avoid it you will never string nouns as adjectives like this again.

Comment: Besides what @David already said, there’s also both *the first laws **targeting** computer crime* as well as *the first laws **to target** computer crime*. Use verbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

*This phrase is ambiguous and it is not possible to use hyphens to rescue it. It should be rewritten.*

If you insist on retaining this phrase as it stands then use three hyphens (computer-crime-targeted) or none (1). However, the hyphens in the resulting phrase will no longer fullfill their original purpose, which was to remove the ambiguity in a phrase containing too many nouns used as adjectives. In general the solution to this problem is to rewrite the phrase with a preposition (2)  e.g.

> First laws targeted at computer crime

In this case a more elegant solution is to use ‘target’ as a verb in its infinitive form, rather than as an adjective, as suggested by @tchrist:

> First laws to target computer crime

**Explanation**

The basic problem is the noun-adjective (3). Although the use of the noun ‘computer’ as an adjective for ‘crime’ is sufficiently common that there is no ambiguity and no need to hyphenate it, when this noun-adjective is itself used as an adjective ambiguity can occur. Hyphenation is one way of removing this ambiguity.

The phrase you are having trouble with contains two such hyphenated pairs, which can be analysed in simplified form using a mathematical or computer-programming system of parentheses to indicate which components go together.

First we have ‘computer crime’ used as an adjective, e.g.

> Computer-crime investigation

where the hyphen replaces the pair in the inner parentheses in pseudo-maths:

> ((Computer crime) investigation)

We also have ‘crime targeted’, e.g.

> Crime-targeted initiative

with a similar representation to the first example in pseudo-maths:

> ((Crime targeted) initiative)

However, the pseudo-maths analysis of your phrase is:

> First (((computer crime) targeted) laws)

This shows that here it is the ‘computer crime’ pair that qualifies ‘targeted’, not ‘crime’, and placing hyphens between the three words makes the relation between each the same, and so does not express the intended meaning.

**Coda**

And it is very ugly.

**References**

The arguments made here stand or fall on their own merits. However, I do provide references to sections of *Fowler’s Modern English Usage
(Second Edition) Revised by Sir Ernest Gowers, Oxford University Press, 1965* for those who are interested. You will need to buy a copy if you wish to consult it — money well spent!

(1) Hyphens 5

> Carelessness,…sometimes leads to the omission of one [hyphen] where it
>   is manifestly a case of all or none. Neither can be dispensed with
>   in…submarine-cable-laying ships.

(2) Hyphens  5 (cont.)

> Some pretty problems in hyphening are set by the unpleasant modern
>   habit of forgetting the existance of prepositions and using a long
>   string of words as a sort of adjectival sea serpent (e.g. “a large
>   vehicle fleet operator mileage restriction has now…”).…Indeed many of
>   our difficulties with hyphens are of our own making: we can avoid them
>   by remembering prepositions…

(3) Noun-Adjectives

> And, what is worse, it is making us forget for instance that, although
>   nursery school is a legitimate use of the noun-adjective, nursery
>   school provision is an ugly and obscure way of saying provision of
>   nursery schools; that if a large vehicle fleet were translated into
>   either a large fleet of vehicles or a fleet of large vehicles an
>   ambiguity would be removed…

Comment: I agree.  I've up-voted your answer & down-voted the earlier answer.

Answer (score -4):

It would be grammatically correct like this:

> First computer crime-targeted laws

`Computer` and `crime` are two separate words.

Take this other example:

> First hacking-targeted laws

It is one word plus `targeted`.

In conclusion, put a space between the two words and a hyphen between the two words and `targeted`.

Comment: Follow up question to the above one - is there any general rules for using hyphens?

Comment: I disagree. There is nothing wrong with saying [computer-crime gang](https://books.google.com/books?id=5PWNWQCOsZ4C&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=%22computer+crime+gang%22&source=bl&ots=SySmWzzbAZ&sig=PS_7_edB4UJBgL6ZdrqKqVXQws4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7i5ORytnMAhXCWD4KHerjACcQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22computer%20crime%20gang%22&f=false). So why not put a hyphen between *computer* and *crime*? People often hyphenate phrases composed of words when they are used as adjectives, such as *one-way street*. [See this reference website](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/576/1/).

Comment: The problem is that computer is a noun used as an adjective with crime, but "computer crime" is being used as an adjective to describe targeted (another adjective). You could have simply "crime-targeted laws" (ugh) but now you end up with a German street named after someone in computer-crime-targeted. The phrase cannot be rescued. He is in an English class and the fault is that he should be using prepositions, not producing an ugly and incomprehensible string of adjectival nouns.

Comment: Your 2 examples are different: *hacking-targeted* is fine, because "hacking" is **one** word; *crime-targeted* is fine, for the same reason; but in *computer crime-targeted*, you need to hyphenate all 3 or none: you are separating "computer" from "crime-targeted", which is nonsense.!